# How to divert a default SQL Server database for web application in C#?

Tags: c#, database, web-applications, sql-server-express

I've created a new web app project template in VS community 2015, when I debug the project, it create its own default SQL Server database in `MSSQLLocalDB` with a default database name like `aspnet-WebDBTest-20151026010545`.

I've tried to change the debug database to a SQL Server Express database.

1. have changed `web.debug.config` file with new connection string on `SQLEXPRESS`

   ```
   <connectionStrings>
       <add name="ApplicationServices"
            connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=TEST;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
            xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(name)" />
   </connectionStrings>
   ```
2. I went to project properties and changed configuration (Active-debug -Any Cpu) changed Database Entry detail, set destination SQL Server database and destination connection string and verified.
3. I even went to Tools > Options > Database Tools > Data Connections
   and set SQL Server Express instance name

But still when I run project in debug mode and add some user data, project is running its default database on `MSSQLLocalDB`

Any ideas? Am I running correct setting? (Please note I've created my destination database on `SQLEXPRESS`)